# DataGrid: прокрутка к последнему элементу

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы при добавлении элементов в DataGrid если количество элементов превышает размер таблицы автоматически прокручивалось к самому нижнему последнему добавленному элементу?

Comment: Вот кто то тут в комментах в самом начале какой то интересный вариант написал с наследованием от какой то коллекции и тут же стер я не успел проверить его. Верните пожалуйста, может это то что надо...

Comment: Вот, держи: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/227459/how-to-set-fucos-on-last-row-of-datagrid

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте, например, использовать метод [ScrollIntoView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673083(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.Items[dataGrid.Items.Count - 1]);
```

Comment: а в обработчике какого события это писать?

Comment: @DarkByte скорее всего при добавлении нового елемента

Comment: @Yurii Manziuk как я уже написал выше - элементы добавляются динамически через биндинг.

Comment: @DarkByte но ведь событие dataGrid.Bind() кто-то вызывает?

Comment: @Aleksandr Zharinov откуда я знаю кто его вызывает? ObservableCollection наверное его вызывает к которой у меня в xaml привязана таблица.

Comment: Я не очень умею в WPF, но можно попробовать использовать метод [OnAddingNewItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.onaddingnewitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Aleksandr Zharinov нет это тоже не то, при добавлении элементов через биндинг это событие не срабатывает.

Comment: @Aleksandr Zharinov так это какой то другой DataGrid из System.Web.UI.WebControls